# The simdlen value when a processor core has multiple vector pipelines

Tags: openmp, vectorization, simd, fpu

I am reading the [OpenMP 4.5](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf) standard and trying to make my mind about the `!$omp simd` / `#pragma omp simd` directive. Specifically, that is not clear for me what are the allowed `simdlen` values.

If I have a processor core with one floating point unit (FPU) capabable of 256-bit vector operations, I would use `simdlen(4)` for 64-bit floating point variables.

But what `simdlen` value should I use if a core has two independent vector pipelines with 128-bit registers?

Comment: What do you mean "two independent pipelines"?  Are you talking about ARM NEON + VFP4?  If so, VFP4 isn't really parallel in hardware.  If you're talking about Ryzen, which has two 128b FMA units, they both use the same xmm or ymm vectors.  For a reduction, you want OpenMP to use multiple accumulators anyway to hide latency, even with one pipeline.  For independent iterations, you don't need to do anything different.

Comment: @PeterCordes, e.g., [this IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/61ad9cf2-c6a3-4d2c-b779-61ff0266d32a/page/1cb956e8-4160-4bea-a956-e51490c2b920/attachment/5d3361eb-3008-4347-bf2f-6bf52e13f060/media/The%20Power8%20Core%20MicroArchitecture%20earlj%20V5.0%20Feb18-2016VUG2.pdf) and [this Intel](https://ark.intel.com/products/120475/Intel-Xeon-Gold-5122-Processor-16_5M-Cache-3_60-GHz) processors have two "FPUs" per core.

Comment: Ok yes, but they use those pipe to increase the throughput of the *same* instruction.  The situation is *exactly* what I described for Ryzen.  OpenMP doesn't have to do anything special beyond the usual loop unrolling for the HW to be able to run more than one FMA per clock, if load/store or anything else isn't a bigger bottleneck.  See http://agner.org/optimize/ for more about tuning code; maybe check the compiler output to see if it did a good job unrolling.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I'm not sure about Intel, but IBM POWER8 does not do that for the _same_ instruction. It processes two independent vector instructions. That is why I do not understand how OpenMP standard treats that.

Comment: I mean two instances of the same instruction.  e.g. `loop: vfmadd132ps zmm0, zmm1, [rdi]`/ `vfmadd132ps zmm4, zmm1, [rdi+64]` /  `...` / `jnz loop` can run at one iteration per clock, because two `vfmadd` instructions can begin every clock cycle.  Instructions with >1 per clock throughput is not special; normal loop unrolling takes advantage of it already.

Comment: The IBM PDF confirms that POWER8 is the same: when running in ST mode, vector FPU instructions are dual-issue.  Otherwise any given thread has all its instructions run on one of the two halves of the execution units, with the two register files separate instead of holding two copies of the same data to let one thread use all the resources.

Comment: @PeterCordes, that means I need to use `simdlen(4)` for loops over arrays of 64-bit reals on POWER8 in ST mode, right?

Comment: POWER8 only has 2-way SIMD for double-precision (16-byte vectors).  From what I can find, all it's supposed to mean is the preferred SIMD register width.  If your compiler unrolls more with `simdlen(4)` (twice as large as the registers it can actually use), then that's probably a good idea.  But make sure it doesn't stop your code from using 512-bit registers with AVX512.  You normally don't need `simdlen()` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

The standard makes no connection between specific hardware architectures and the `simdlen` clause of the `simd` construct, so it's implementation defined.

---

I would first add the question: **Do you need to use `simdlen` at all?**

From my experience with different implementations with AVX2 and AVX-512, I'd say: **no, it is no necessary** in order to utilise both VPUs per core on Xeon and Xeon Phi, but it can be somewhat beneficial for the performance of the generated code to use twice the native register size as argument. I think the intended use is a different one (see background).

**From the standard:**

According to the standard (p. 74, l. 22), the `simdlen` clause for the `simd` construct (as opposed to the `declare simd` construct) specifies the **preferred** behaviour, while the **actual** behaviour, and thus the answer to the original question, is implementation defined:

> If used, the simdlen clause specifies the preferred number of iterations to be executed concurrently. The parameter of the simdlen clause must be a constant positive integer. The number of iterations that are executed concurrently at any given time is **implementation defined**.

The only constraints for the **allowed value** stated in the standard are:

> The parameter of the safelen clause must be a **constant positive integer** expression.
>
> If both simdlen and safelen clauses are specified, the value of the simdlen parameter must be less than or equal to the value of the safelen parameter.

**Background:**

> The simdlen clause was added to the simd construct (see Section 2.8.1 on page 72) to support specification of the exact number of iterations desired per SIMD chunk.

This can be used to call a matching SIMD-function generated with the `declare simd` construct and a corresponding `simdlen` clause, where the latter has slightly different semantics:

> If a SIMD version is created, the number of concurrent arguments for the function is determined by the simdlen clause.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So using a wider `simdlen` tricks your compiler into unrolling more than it normally would?  Which compiler are you using?  This is obviously compiler-specific.

Comment: Didn't analyse the assembly, but observed consistent changes in runtime. Used the Intel Compiler (Linux), 2016 and 2017 release (probably 2018, too).